# General linear model for binomial data - zeros problem

Tags: binary, glm, zero, posthoc, glmmtmb

I am a young researcher and I am interested in animal behaviour.

In my experiment I looked at the expression of a behaviour for which I gave a score: score 0 when the behaviour was not expressed and score 1 when it was expressed. I therefore have binary data (0/1).
In this study I observed each animal several times (5 animals observed). Each animal was observed at different Ages (0 month, 1 month, 2 months, 3 months). For each age I made several observations per animal. I therefore have data with a repeated measurement.

I want to evaluate the effect of age on the expression of behaviour.

Here are my data :

> table(data$Score, data$Age)
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOiRA.png)

There is an imbalance in my data because some observations were not valid. They have therefore been deleted.
You can see that my 0month old animals (in red) never expressed the behaviour. So there is only a score of 0 and that is what I have a problem with.

To analyse my data I first made a glmer to evaluate the effect of my different variables:

> glm (Score ~ Age + Animal + Observation, family=binomial(link = "logit"), data=data)

The variables Age and Animal influence the score. The variable Observation does not influence the score so I do not consider it anymore.

In a second step I created a glmer :

> glmer (Score ~ Age + (1|Animal), family=binomial(link = "logit"), data=data)

I got two warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, :
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, :
Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined

I then read up on different forums. If I understood correctly it is advised to use a glmmTMB for data with a large number of zeros. So that's what I did.
I managed to stop getting the error messages and my model is running:

> glmmTMB(Score ~ Age + (1|Animal), family=binomial(link = "logit"), data=data)

However, when I display a summary of my model, the 0month group seems to be a problem because it comes out with a p-value =1 (in red):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Fep.png)

I also observe a p-value=1 when I do the post hoc test :

> summary(glht(model, linfct = mcp(Age = "Tukey")))
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZl5h.png)

My questions are the following:

- Is the construction of my model correct?
- Does the glmmTMB model fit my data?
- How do I get my model to accept that the 0 month group consists only of 0 scores?
- Am I using the right post-hoc test?

I have been stalling on this problem for a week. I thank you in advance for your precious help.